# Integration of numerical data

Tags: matlab, numerical, numerical-integration

I'm writing a test tomorrow and I'm contemplating doing everything on Matlab, to save time.

Some questions require numerical integration of datapoints (**points, not necessarily functions**).

E.g.

```
C=[0 1 5 8 10 8 6 4 3 2.2 1.5 0.6 0];
```

I've used `trapz(C)` to determine the integral of the data (area under the curve) and compared that to what my textbook gets.
Often, there is too large a difference between the two.

Is there another **easy and fast** way that the above data can be integrated numerically using Matlab, e.g. by using Simpson's rule, Gauleg or spline?

I've taken a look at `integrate()`, but that seems to work only on functions?

Comment: Different methods are listed here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration . What do you need?

Comment: I guess I could have stated that in the question.

I know about other methods, such as Simpsons, Gauleg, Spline, etc. I know I can do them by hand (big no-no for the test). I also have Polymath to my disposal, which can do the aforementioned methods. The thing is, I want to use those results again without copying and assembling new data, or switching between programs, or between computer and paper.

Comment: Hint: combine: `integral` with something like `interp1(...,'cubic')` or `interp1(...,'spline')`. Otherwise you'll need to implement your own methods (or look on the [File Exchange](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/?utf8=✓&term=quadrature) / Google).

Comment: Interpolation seems like the best bet. I'll try them and then compare the integration results again

Comment: That seems to do the trick! Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Are your data points spaced by dx = 1?  if dx is .5 for example, this would change the result by a factor of two.

Otherwise, I'd point out: the data point by themselves, assuming zero width, will produce an area of 0: the point being that your textbook must be assuming some kind of interpolation between them to get a meaningful integral.  If they are straight line segements, trapz(C) should give you the correct result; if your textbook is doing something else (points taken from a smooth function, for example), it is not surprising the results would be different.

Comment: What actually happened is that I for some reason did not do trapz(t,C). That is the most correct way of doing it, and that sorts out the dx

Comment: Yes, as I said might be the case.  You can do this either with an argument, or just multiply it trap(C)*dx